# How to call require files from public_html to wordpress theme directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to call two require files from public_html to WordPress theme directory,

Example - `require 'includes/functions.php';
require 'init.php';`

those files are located in public_html and i am calling from public_html/wp-content/themes/arkahost/header.php

I modified require condition, but still no luck.  anyone have an idea behind it?

Comment: `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/functions.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Take the whole path to include the files.

For example ,

```
require( '/home/username/public_html/include-shared.php' );
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is:

The best way is: `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'somefilename.php';`